# Swap Pancakeswap using Nethereum

Tags: web3js, nethereum

i dont find any examples or snippets for Nethereum. How can i swap Tokens via Pancakeswap on Nethereum?

Thanks for help

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i work on it. at the moment i have error "transaction underpriced: eth_sendRawTransaction". if its complete i can sent you the code